# Mongoose Set object property in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document consisting of a Post. Each Post has an array of Comments, which are an object each. So my document looks like this

[image]

Now, I want to be able to update the message property in a given Comment object.

So I'll be using the $set method, but how would I be able to select the specific object. Currently, my unfinished method looks like this

```
export const editComment = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;

  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

  const _id = post.id;

  const postComments = post.comments.map((comment) => comment._id);

  const commentIndex = postComments.indexOf(id.id);

  const message = post.comments[commentIndex].message;

    try {
      await Post.updateOne(
        { _id },
        {
          $set: {
            // Action to update the comment
          },
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.status(200).json({ message: post });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
```

I figured selecting the right index of the comment was a good start, but how would I, in the $set method, select the correct Comment object, and then update the message property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the right data in database and update its required property. You can do it by the following method

```
exports.updateMessage= async (_id,objectId, newMessage) => {
    return await TableName.updateOne({_id: _id},{{comments: {$elemMatch: {_id: objectId}$set:{message:newMessage}}});
};
```

Comment: Returns error The dollar ($) prefixed field '$elemMatch' in 'comments.0.$elemMatch' is not valid for storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.updateOne(_id,

{
  $set: {
    "comments.$[elem].message": "the value you want to set for message"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem._id": 1 // _id of comment object you want to edit
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Method goes through without errors but the object is not updated

Comment: could you log your query ?